# SQL Storage logic between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm, logic

I would really like to have your help. I'm getting the following problem.

I have a products store app, that a I input two dates (`DATETIME`), the initial and the final date.

And a I need to validate all the exceptions, for example:

I reserved an item from

> 15:00 to 17:00.

Then I CAN'T reserve this item during this time.

Here go some examples:

> From 14:00 to 16:00 [ no ]
>   From 15:00 to 16:00 [ no ]
>   From 16:00 to 18:00 [ no ]
>   From 12:00 to 14:00 [ yes ]
>   From 17:00 to 19:00 [ yes ]

Look this code, that's what I already could do. (noob).

```
SET @START = DATE('2013-06-06 15:30:00');
SET @FINAL = DATE('2013-06-06 16:00:00');

INSERT INTO `store` (`start_date`, `final_date`) VALUES ('2013-06-06 15:00:00', '2013-06-06 17:00:00');
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'NO', 'YES') FROM `Store` WHERE
    (`start_date` BETWEEN @START AND @FINAL); -- OUTPUT 'NO'
```

With this code I resolve the problem that I can validate what's BETWEEN the two dates, but if one of the dates informed are out of those ranges it fails.

Remembering that I can use a backend language to help too.

Thank you

Comment: what is the issue ? You can use that query

Comment: Please include your actual code. External links can be helpful, but should be in addition to including the code in the question.

Comment: `but if one of the dates informed are out of those ranges it fails.` For example date please

Comment: From 14:00 to 16:00 [ no ]
From 15:00 to 16:00 [ no ]
From 16:00 to 18:00 [ no ]
From 12:00 to 14:00 [ yes ]
From 17:00 to 19:00 [ yes ]

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if either of the "attempt to reserve" date/times fall between the "reserved" date/time range:

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) = 0, 'NO', 'YES')
FROM Store
WHERE @Start BETWEEN start_date AND final_date
   OR @Final BETWEEN start_date AND final_date
```

If the count is zero, the time slot is *not* reserved. If it's greater than zero, the time slot *is* reserved.